# Prevent user accessing the Apache2 page?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I just deployed a new VPS with `Ubuntu Server 16.04` and I installed `LAMP` to host some websites. If i navigate from the browser to `IP_of_my_VPS`, I will see the default page of `Apache2`.

Should I leave it as it is or should I prevent the user from accessing the default page of `Apache2` ? Is there any danger ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you prevent users from accessing the default page if you are not going to be using the default page or replacing the default page with something else.

To prevent a user from accessing the page, do:

chmod 700 /

e.g
chmod 700 /var/www/html

Restart your Apache service once done.

Comment: Other than the aesthetics, why would this be a recommendation? What is the danger of leaving the default page up?